# Check if string in the exact form of "<int1>,<int2>" in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm converting a string of two integers into a tuple. I need to make sure my string is formatted exactly in the form of `"<int1>,<int2>"` with the comma, and no extra spaces.

I know that is `isdigit()` can be used to check if a given string contains only digits. However, this doesn't address the required comma and no spaces.

Here is my code to convert the string to a tuple of integers:

```
s1 = "12,24"
string_li = s1.split(',')
num_li = [int(x) for x in string_li]
num_tuple = tuple(num_li)
```

It was suggested Regex could be used here. How would I implement this into an if/else statement? This is working, but doesn't appear to be correct:

```
import re
s1 = '12,24'
if re.match("^\d+,\d+$",s1) is not None:
    print("pass")
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: That code seems good already. If you think there may be bad input, you could put your processing into a `try` block and catch the relevant exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for regular expressions.

```
import re
re.match("^\d+,\d+$", some_string)
```

- `^` matches start of string
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `,` matches comma literal
- `$` matches end of string

Some testcases:

```
assert re.match("^\d+,\d+$", "123,123")
assert not re.match("^\d+,\d+$", "123,123 ")  # trailing whitespace
assert not re.match("^\d+,\d+$", " 123,123")  # leading whitespace 
assert not re.match("^\d+,\d+$", "a,b")  # not digits
assert not re.match("^\d+,\d+$", "-1,3")  # minus sign is invalid
```

Return value of `re.match` is either [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) or `None`, fortunately they behave as expected in boolean context - `MatchObject` is truthy and `None` is falsy, as can be seen is assert statements above.

Comment: No, it's either [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) or `None`, fortunately they behave as expected in boolean context - `MatchObject` is truthy and `None` is falsy.

Comment: no it's "if match" and "if not match", obviously you need to use the full statement and just not if match

Comment: `if re.match("^\d+,\d+$", some_string):` will work as expected.